# How to remove custom cookies added in AD B2C by custom UI while logout

Tags: cookies, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am using AD B2C custom policies with my own custom UI. For some purpose I'm adding some cookies. As the UI runs under B2C domain (eg: tenant.b2clogin.com) these custom cookies are created under this domain.I need to found a way to remove these customised cookies when we do the B2C logout. I know the B2C has a way to redirect to a logout URL, but, I'm not sure it will work because this URL is out of the B2C domain when the cookies are created. Do you have a suggestion about how to customise the logout to remove these custom cookies placed under B2C domain?

Answer (score 2):

Currently we can not customize the sign out UI directly by using custom page layouts.

When you logout from your web app you should redirect to B2C's logout endpoint as described in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-a-sign-out-request).

> When you want to sign the user out of the application, it isn't enough
> to clear the application's cookies or otherwise end the session with
> the user. Redirect the user to Azure AD B2C to sign out. If you fail
> to do so, the user might be able to reauthenticate to your application
> without entering their credentials again.

The logout endpoint can receive an optional post_logout_redirect_uri parameter in the query string, where you can specify another URL where your user will be finally redirected by B2C. That can be the address of any resource, e.g. you homepage or your own page showing a "You successfully logged out of our service" message to the user.

> post_logout_redirect_uri - The URL that the user should be redirected
> to after successful sign out. If it isn't included, Azure AD B2C shows
> the user a generic message.